# Solspace Super Search - random results for the title field

Tags: supersearch

I'm getting some weird search results with Super Search in relation to the title field.

Channel Videos: I have 3 entries called Video Gallery 1, Video Gallery 2 & Video Gallery 3

Channel Images: I have 3 entries called Image Gallery 1, Image Gallery 2 & Image Gallery 3

Please note the capitalization of the search terms.

If I search for the term "gallery" I get 6 results.

If I search for the term "Gallery" I get 6 results.

If I search for the term "image" I get 3 results.

If I search for the term "Image" I get 3 results.

If I search for the term "Image Gallery" I get 3 results.

If I search for the term "image gallery" I get 0 results.

Why on earth does the search appear to be case sensitive on the last one? It makes no sense.

Here's the code that fixed my issue:

```
    <h2 class="title">
            Search Media <i class="corner"></i>
        </h2>
        <div class="row search-box">
            <form class="col-xs-12" action="{path='media-gallery/jim-sol'}/" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}" /> <!-- Important! --> 
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="keywords"
                    id="keywords"
                    placeholder="Search Media">
                <input type="submit" value="" class="serch-butt" >
            </form>
        </div>
            <h2>Video Results super_search_total_results = {super_search_total_results}</h2>
            {exp:super_search:results
               channel="media_videos"
                status="open|featured"
            }
    {if super_search_no_results}
                <p>Sorry, no results were found.</p>
            {/if}
    <h3>{title}</h3>
    {/exp:super_search:results}

            <h2>Image Results super_search_total_results = {super_search_total_results}</h2>
            {exp:super_search:results
               channel="media_images"
                status="open|featured"
            }
    {if super_search_no_results}
                <p>Sorry, no results were found.</p>
            {/if}
    <h3>{title}</h3>
    {/exp:super_search:results}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having trouble with case sensitive search results as well using Super Search.

Comment: Hi Brad, I opened a support request with Solspace who provided me with a template that worked for me. I'll send you a PM with it attached.

Comment: I couldn't see how to PM you so I've added the code to my initial question.